# strip <br>(n12br) get from database field

Tags: php, textarea, strip-tags, nl2br

i have a textarea value which its value derived from a field(nl2br)

how to strip off "< br/>", so that when i want to edit this field, the "< br />" will not be appeared?

```
//$data["Content"] is the field that has <br/> tags inside
$content = $data["Content"];

//when want to edit, want to strip the <br/> tag
<td><textarea name="content" rows="10" style="width:300px;"><?=$content?></textarea></td>
```

i know it should be using strip_tags() function but not sure the real way to do it

any help would be appreciated

Comment: i have found the way finally. just use strip_tags($content) and it should work fine.

Comment: use `strip_tags()` if you wanna remove every html element from your variable, if you wanna just remove the `<br/>` use a function like `str_replace()`. if you are editing for example blog posts you better add a javascript editor in your interface, it'll make your like much easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanna use strip_tags, then it would just be:

```
$content = strip_tags($data["Content"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

i would be using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) the following will replace `<br/>` with newline

```
$content = str_replace('<br/>','\n',$data['Content']);
```

or if you don't want the newline

```
$content = str_replace('<br/>','',$data['Content']);
```

**edit**
an example

```
$my_br = 'hello<br/> world';
$content = str_replace('<br/>','',$my_br);

echo $content;

Output: hello world
```

Comment: That won't remove <br /> or <br>

Comment: @Niklas but it'll remove `<br/>` and not the rest of the html element. he only requested `<br/`>

Comment: yea this won't replace the <br/> in fact.. so i think i will stick with the strip_tags()

Comment: @user723360 of course it does, check my example, keep in mind that this only removes `<br/>` not `<br />` or `<br>`. If you like to remove all and only the occurrences of `<br>` you must run `str_replace` for all of the above.

Comment: @atno i not sure why.. perhaps the nl2br problem as the value get from database. i have try this $content = str_replace('<br/>','\n',$data['Content']); but the <br/> tags still appear in the textarea.

Comment: @user723360 `$content = str_replace('<br/>','',$data['Content']);` you must assign the output of str_replace to a variable and then print it on the screen